# Gson parsing into Object that contains a JsonArray

Tags: java, android, gson

See solution at the end.

**original question**

I have the following object in my code that I'm trying to deserialize with Gson.

```
public class Foo {
    public Map<String, JSONArray> bar = new HashMap<>();
    public ... other stuff
}
```

I've also tried with:

```
public class Foo {
    public Map<String, String> bar = new HashMap<>();
    public ... other stuff
}
```

The reason here is because the `Map` will be feed into sub-modules that could be any data type. Internally each module knows how to parse its own data.

on the `JsonArray` version I get this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 3 column 18 path $.trigger.
```

and in the `String` version I get this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
   Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 3 column 18 path $.trigger.
```

My question is:

Can I parse this without the need of a custom deserializer? How?

**Edit:** below is the relevant bits of code:

```
// Gson is singleton provided by Dagger2
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

// retrofit is also singleton provided by dagger
Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .client(buildOkHttpClient(context))
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
return restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);

// then the Retrofit API
@GET("our path")
Observable<Foo> getFoo(a couple of values);
```

I've also tried using a MockTransport that is directly invoking Gson, like following:

```
Observable
   .just(fooResponse)
   .delay(101, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .map(new Function<String, Foo>() {
      @Override public Interactions apply(String s) throws Exception {
           return gson.fromJson(s, Foo.class);
       }
    });
```

and below relevant parts of the JSON:

```
{
  "bar": {
    "type0": [
      {
        ... object 0
      }
    ],
    "type1": [
      {
        ... object 0
      },
      {
        ... object 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "otherStuff" : {
  }
}
```

The json is for sure formatted correctly, it's coming from our servers and I've re-checked on jsonlint.com

**solution:**

it seems that is not possible to do without custom deserializer. So I wrote a serialiser for String, which sounds bad, but I' gladly accept suggestions of a better way of handling it.

```
.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new JsonDeserializer<String>() {
   @Override
   public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            return json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
        } else {
            return json.toString();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: How do you deserialize `Foo` instances? Something like `gson.from(..., Foo.class)`?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv yes. exactly like that. I'll update the question with those details.

Comment: Will Also be helpful if you added a sample json of what you want to deserialize

Comment: The exception message you provided is saying that the JSON top-most property `$.trigger` is an array (_... but was BEGIN_ARRAY at ..._), but your Gson mapping (POJO) is declared like something else, probably `Map<String, ...>` that you probably mentioned as `bar` in your Gson mapping.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I've added the Json base structure and how I'm accessing it.

Comment: @KoustavRay added

Comment: @Budius The exception is saying that you have the `trigger` property. Could you provide it both in your JSON and POJO? Or is it just the `bar` field from `Foo`? If so, then your mapping looks legit though and the issue may come from somewhere else... What if you change your `Map<String, ...>` to `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv `trigger` is the `bar` object. I'll give a shot with `Object`.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv with `Object` it creates a `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`. I mean, I guess I'll have to write a custom deserializer.

Comment: @Budius Yes, this is the default Gson behaviour, because Gson does not have enough type information. If you have a precisely known-structure JSON (not arbitrary), then you probably could map it to `Map<String, List<YourCustomMappingClass>>`. If not, then a custom deserializer is necessary.

Comment: @Budius Did you try my answer? It will deserialize your json string without a custom deserializer.

Comment: @Budius The JSON given is an object and not Array..

Should have tried `public class Foo {
    public Map<String, JSONObject> bar = new HashMap<>();
    public ... other stuff
}`

Comment: @KoustavRay thanks for the suggestion, but that was "divyansh ingle" answer and it still doesn't work. Check my comment there.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you are trying to parse JsonArray but you should parse JsonObject at above mentioned line.
I hope it will help!! :)

Comment: I still got "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 3 column 18 path $.trigger"

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this it was working fine for me,

```
public class Foo {

    Map<String, List<Map>> bar = new HashMap<String, List<Map>>() ;

}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work without crash. But it does not solve the question, as the data inside the map is "abstract" and and will be string parsed later on. On my description: "The reason here is because the Map will be feed into sub-modules that could be any data type. Internally each module knows how to parse its own data"